# Set Identification - bag 2 is gold, dark blue, greys

Tags: set-identification

What set do these parts belong?

[image: bag 2 is gold, dark blue, greys]

Answer (score 8):

It looks like [76141-1 Thanos Mech](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76141-1)

[image: 76141-1 Thanos Mech]

The part [27263 Tile, Modified Facet 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=27263&in=S) doesn't show up in many sets in Pearl Gold or Metallic Gold.